# Array in object[][]

Tags: java

I am working on inserting a list of array inside an object. Using that object I have created, I am planning to use it inside another object as it is required to use it in my JTable.

This is my object class.

```
class MyData {
private String name;

public MyData(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

My main class is:

```
    String[] tt = {"aa"};
    MyData[] thePlayers = new MyData[0];
        for(int i = 0;i < tt.length;i++){
            thePlayers[i] = new MyData(tt[i]);
        }

    Object[][] data = {{"2"}};
    String[] headers = { "Income Type" };
    JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
```

I am receiving this error on my system
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

What might be the cause of it? Ive tried all means, but I still cant figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I encounter a different hurdle which is initializing 
Object[][].

Example :

```
Object[][] data;
```

How do we initialize this in a forloop using above code we have applied in ThePlayers?

Lastly, when i run the program, it didnt display as what is specified in the array. [image]

Comment: With `new MyData[0];` you are creating an array of length zero. You need to create an array with the appropriate length. For example: `new MyData[1];`

Comment: For convenience, recommend to use ArrayList instead of String Array

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments but just initialize the MyData object array corresponding to input data array length

```
MyData[] thePlayers = new MyData[tt.length];
        for(int i = 0;i < tt.length;i++){
            thePlayers[i] = new MyData(tt[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays in Java have static size. In the second line of your main class u declare `thePlayers` with size 0 - you won't be able to put anything in it.
Simple fix is to initialize array with the appropriate size.

```
String[] tt = {"aa"};
MyData[] thePlayers = new MyData[tt.length];
for(int i = 0;i < tt.length;i++){
    thePlayers[i] = new MyData(tt[i]);
}

Object[][] data = {{"2"}};
String[] headers = { "Income Type" };
JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
```

Other option would be to use something like a `List` with dynamic size.